# Filling a plane with triangles (Triangulation)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, triangulation, triangular

I tried to create an image like the one below as a random background for a website, but after multiple attempts I couldn't find an algorithm that gets the job done.

[image]

**What should the program do?**

It should be able to fill a plane randomly with triangles. These triangles should all be independent, so I don't simply want to draw long lines on the canvas an color the triangles that are created.

**Algorithms I've tried so far:**

**1.**

- Make random Points
- Make random Connections with a length below a specific value (This could leed to holes in the triangle net)
- Try to find out what connections make a triangle (I failed here)

**2.**

- Start with a single triangle
- Create a new Point close to an existing connection and add a triangle from there that doesn't cause any intersections. This lead to problems whenever it left a little hole like in this picture:

  [image]

**3.**

- Make random points
- Make all possible connections (every point to every other)
- Sort the connections by length
- For every connection starting with the shortest draw if it isn't intersecting with any other drawn line. Otherwise delete the connection.

This was actually my best attemt even if it took the program far to long to get it done with only a few points. This is how the result looked:

[image]

I didn't find a way to find out what connections make a triangle and therefor I couldn't color them indipendently...

So hopefully you know a way to create a nice triangle-filled canvas like in the first picture and let me know...

Comment: Couldnt you set one point, draw e.g. 4 randomly around and connect them with the middle one and around, then repeat with more points.

Comment: Google *Delaunay triangulation*.

Comment: Further to @spug's suggestion: Delaunay triangulations have the property that they maximise the smallest angle of any triangle -- that is, they avoid creating "long skinny" triangles (whenever it's possible to do so).

Comment: To be pedantic, the example image isn't a Delauney triangulation so doing that won't produce an image "like the one below", if that's important

Comment: @samgak Well, all I want it to do is looking good... for that a Delaunay triangulation should work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution is to start with random points (with your preferred distribution) and apply some [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_triangulation) algorithm. Among these, the Delaunay triangulation is a good candidate, for its low computational complexity and code availability.

Comment: I'm thankful for the tip, but I don't think this solves my problem with saving every single triangle as an object to be able to ultimately color them...

Comment: @AntonBallmaier: you are wrong to think that. A triangulation algorithm can allow you to enumerate all the faces, and create a triangle for each.

Comment: Well, then thanks a lot for your advice :) Oh, and take those 15 rep. :P

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved without triangulation, similarly to the second approach. Only generating new points will lead to this more and more concave pattern, but if between additions one connects points that are not connected but could be (meaning that there is a point to which both of them are connected, and the new line wouldn't intersect with any other) (adding a new triangle) this doesn't occur. (In my opinion it's better to only add such lines under some length limitation.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).